How to specify which glibc and libstdc++ to run the program, without sudo
I want to run a program on CentOS, but I met problem with the libstdc++ and glibc. I can't update both because I have no root privileges, and I would like the solution to only affect this particular program.

First, I met
version GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found

so I download the libstdc++.so.6.0.29 from the internet and performet
ln -s /my_libstdc_path/libstdc++.so.6.0.29 /my_libstdc_path/libstdc++.so.6

I also ran
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my_libstdc_path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

before executing the program.
Then, I met
version GLIBC_2.18 not found

I used
strings /my_libstdc_path/libstdc+++.so.6 | grep GLIBC_2.18

and I found the GLIBC_2.18, this is confusing.
Just to be safe, I also downloaded the glibc-2.18 and compiled it, and added
source ~/.bashrc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my_glib_path/glibc-2.18/lib:/my_libstdc_path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_PRELOAD=/my_glib_path/glibc-2.18/lib/libc.so.6



Now I get
151115 Segmentation fault

How can I solve it?

This could be anything, from any other library not working as expected, to a bug, to the program crashing because anything else is not as it expects it. Likely is also that you didn't quite use the compiler settings and configure options that the program originally expected from its libc/libc++
The usual solution is to recompile the program for your platform, not the other way around. If that isn't possible, run the program in a container containing of the original platform it was built for.
